# Parsing tuber logs via Airflow (tuber) API

Tags: java, apache-spark, directed-acyclic-graphs, airflow-api

I am very new to the Airflow (tuber) and will appreciate help with it.
We have an application that submits DAGs to the tuber. Generated DAG-ID is being stored in the database. When scheduled jobs are running, task are submitted to the Spark servers for execution.

Now I need to develop a daemon application that will retrieve those DAG-IDs, find DAGRun-Ids, find spark task ids and retrieve from spark servers statuses and events of those spark tasks.
I am browsing Airflow API and see how to get DAG runs for a particular DAG Id, but can't find how to get further information.
However, through Airflow UI I can see DAGRun log with spark task URIs with spark task ID which can be used to get info, I am looking for. But I don't know how to do it programmatically in Java.
If someone has done something similar, I would greatly appreciate any tips or hints.